# Using DAX to Create a dynamic horizontal line for a bar or line chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hello Lovely People of SO,

I hope you guys are having a great day!

I have the following dataset

| REGION | ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DC | 1 | NEW |
| ED | 2 | NEW |
| FR | 3 | OLD |
| FR | 4 | NEW |
| GI | 5 | OLD |
| GI | 6 | OLD |
| GY | 7 | NEW |
| GY | 8 | OLD |
| GY | 9 | OLD |
| GY | 10 | OLD |
| GY | 11 | OLD |
| GY | 12 | NEW |
| RT | 13 | NEW |
| TX | 14 | NEW |
| TX | 15 | NEW |

I will first want to know how to use `DAX` to calculate the percentage of `ID` with `STATUS` ="OLD" by `REGION`

Intuitivatly in Python I can group by REGION and then summarize the number of OLD and NEW STATUS but here in PBI DAX things are not somewhat stright forward yet for me since I am learning so thanks you for helping my out with that, my main goal is to create a bar chart that will show the percentage of OLD STATUS by REGION and add a horizontal line that will display the global average of percentages, this is my own data summary

[image]

and my desired viz would look like this:

[image]

but I have no clue was to how to do that in dax in power bi thank you so much if you guys can help me out If you can reference some code online to do this or if there is a special bulti-in function to calculate this horizontal line thanks a million I will be super attentive to all of your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and let me know if It works for you:

```
OldPercent_Measure =
VAR TblSummary =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( YourTable, YourTable[REGION] ),
        "STATUS OLD",
            CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( YourTable ) + 0, YourTable[STATUS] = "OLD" ),
        "TOTAL", CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( YourTable ) ),
        "% OLD",
            ROUND (
                DIVIDE (
                    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( YourTable ) + 0, YourTable[STATUS] = "OLD" ),
                    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( YourTable ) )
                ),
                2
            )
    )
VAR PercentOld =
    SUMX ( TblSummary, [% OLD] )
VAR GlobalAverage =
    AVERAGEX ( TblSummary, [% OLD] )

RETURN
    PercentOld
```

Then create a column chart, put [REGION] column in X_axis, and put OldPercent_Measure in the Y_axis[Values field]. I hope It solves your problem.

To calculate Global Average, the same code above. The only difference is to replace PercentOld with GlobalAverage after "RETURN" statement. Like This:

......
......
RETURN
GlobalAverage

[image: Global Average]

Extra Info:
You want to see the result of your summary table:

```
EVALUATE
VAR TblSummary =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( YourTable, YourTable[REGION] ),
        "STATUS OLD",
            CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( YourTable ) + 0, YourTable[STATUS] = "OLD" ),
        "TOTAL", CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( YourTable ) ),
        "% OLD",
            ROUND (
                DIVIDE (
                    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( YourTable ) + 0, YourTable[STATUS] = "OLD" ),
                    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( YourTable ) )
                ),
                2
            )
    )
VAR PercentOld =
    SUMX ( TblSummary, [% OLD] )
RETURN
    TblSummary
```

Resulting Screen:

[image: FFFFFFFFF04]

To find out how to put average line:
You need to go analytics pane.
Here is a good link to do that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-analytics-pane

[image: FFFd]

Comment: Ozan thank you so much for this answer and the TIME you took to help me out this was such an excellent explanation and you taught me so much about DAX and aggregation measures !

Comment: Hi @R_Student I am pleased to hear it . That was my ultimate goal when I decided to answer your question. Stay safe!

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the average for OLD is to create a calculated column for %.  Then use DAX to find the average of just the ones with OLD status, using:

CALCULATE(AVERAGE([% column]), FILTER(table name, STATUS = “OLD”))

Answer (score 1):

The graph is a cummulative histogramm (the second left to right, top line). The line is a constant line at analytics. I used the same measure for value there. Have a nice day.

```
Rate = 
VAR Regions = VALUES(tbl[REGION])
VAR sumOfRates=
        SUMX(
            Regions
            ,DIVIDE(
                CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('tbl'),tbl[STATUS]="OLD")
                ,CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('tbl'))
            )
        )
RETURN 
    DIVIDE(sumOfRates,COUNTROWS(Regions))+0
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Mik thank you for your time and effort your answer is excellent may I ask you... why do you use a "+0" at the end?

Comment: Hi, thanks. It's an old trick with  `+0`. The reason is to show values that are BLANK().  This expression substitutes BLANK() with 0.